# How to call function from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a form design on Qtdesigner and have two class.

I want to use some variable from  method `addItem()` while in method `getText()`.

I don't know how to achieve this goal. Can someone please give me some tips?

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
 class App(QWidget):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

     def getText(self):
         text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Get text", "Your name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
         if okPressed and text != '':
             wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('hello.xlsx')
             wb.save(text+ '.xlsx')
```

This is where I want to call method `addItem()`.

```
class AppWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()

    def addItem(self):
        auditdate = self.dateEdit.date()
        a = auditdate.toPyDate()
        area = self.lineEdit_Area.text()
```

Here is where I want to use variable text from above DialogBox.

Comment: For example, which variables of method `addItem()`, you are gonna use in your method `getText()`. Just give a clue. Anyways, you can place `AppWindow` class before `App` and create an object `AppWindow` from within `getText()` method and call `addItem()`. There are other ways too. It depends, how are you gonna do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try your solution and will update. This is my first time here on this site and not sure if i can paste all my code? Anyway, I was first going to run getText() . where excel file template called "hello.xlsx" gets saved as with the name provided by user from dialogbox. After that i was going to go to addItem(), open that saved excel file and write the user data. This is where I am having problem. When I do self.addItem(), it doesn’t go to addItem. Hope that makes sense. 

Thanks

Comment: Finally figure it out but not sure if is the right way. This is how i did. when submit button pressed, go to addItem. addItem writes data to excel file and saves it. from here dialogbox is called. Ask user to enter the file name and open last saved excel file and save it as user input file name. For some reason i couldn't go other way around (like first go to dialog and to addItem).

Comment: There is not nearly enough here to go on—the structure of the overall program determines the correct way of passing information from one part to another.

Comment: I hear you Davis. This was my first time posting here, so wasn't sure about placing entire code. I finally figure it out to put entire code and now it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855859/writing-image-to-excel-file-same-workbook-but-different-sheet                                                                          I was able to make everything work, except now stuck with writing image to excel file. Thanks to all you guys to get me this far.